# schedule a schedule notification using firebase cloud messaging for flutter reminder app

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing a flutter reminder app that can schedule a daily notification with the time of day given from user.

At first i try `flutter_local_notifications` package and i can schedule the notification using `zonedSchedule()` method. However, it only works when the app is in foreground state.

Therefore, i try firebase cloud messaging (FCM) to send notification when app is in background state or terminated. In the website of FCM where you can send a test notification to the phone, i find that there is an option to schedule the notification by choosing the time and 'repeat' value.

The question is, how can i do that from flutter app? What i mean is how can my flutter app send the value of time to fcm so that it can send the notification to the phone daily at that time?. I have tried the method of sending POST request but ít seems that the request does not have the field where you can pass the time parameter. I can only pass other parameters like title, body, data,...

Or if firebase cloud messaging does not work like that, can you suggest me other options?

[image]